# Posting Japanese message to wall

Tags: unicode, internationalization, facebook-wall

I've tried to post Japanese message to wall from my Android app via Facebook SDK.
But the message is shown like `&amp;#26085;&amp;#26412;&amp;#35486;` on the wall (it should be `日本語`).

Do I need to do something before posting?

**P.S** Of course English message is shown correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My guess is that you are probably doing some entities encode somewhere in your android application. 

If I decoded that string it is showed up fine.

Comment: Thnak you Janar. But I already solved the problem. The text message is html encoded in other part. So I've decoded it and sent to Facebook. It's shown correctly.